# Delete [work] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Can the [work](/questions/tagged/work) be deleted? I would just remove the tag myself, but there are lots of questions tagged with it that shouldn't be on SO in the first place.

Question with the tag are about:

- work as in job related -> offtopic
- work as in versioning -> retag to [working-directory](/questions/tagged/working-directory) / [working-copy](/questions/tagged/working-copy)
- work as in it doesn't work

**EDIT**

I just found this kinda related question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120995/get-rid-of-working-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holy cow that was a bad one. Thanks for pointing it out.

It is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: You're on fire :)

Comment: What should we do with the (currently six) questions that became untagged?  Retag and vote to close?  They're all prehistoric and now Not Constructive or Off Topic.